# How to create ".psh" file?

Tags: android, libgdx

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MeshColorTexture

I wonder how to create ".psh" file for my own PolygonRegion?

[image]

Retrieved code from sample of libgdx http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/PolygonSpriteTest.java

```
@Override
            public void create () {
                texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/tree.png"));
                region = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(texture), Gdx.files.internal("data/tree.psh"));

                renderer = new ShapeRenderer();

                camera = new OrthographicCamera(480, 320);
                camera.position.x = 240;
                camera.position.y = 160;
                camera.update();

                batch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();

                for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
                    PolygonSprite sprite = new PolygonSprite(region);
                    sprite.setPosition(MathUtils.random(-30, 440), MathUtils.random(-30, 290));
                    sprite.setColor(MathUtils.random(), MathUtils.random(), MathUtils.random(), 1.0f);
                    sprite.setScale(MathUtils.random(0.5f, 1.5f), MathUtils.random(0.5f, 1.5f));
                    sprites.add(sprite);
                }
            }
```

We can see that **"tree.psh"** file is being used on the the third line of the code. Is there any kind of converter or editor? How are we supposed to create this kind of file?

Answer (score 6):

libgdx apparently has its own editor, [libgdx-polygoneditor](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-polygoneditor/downloads/detail?name=polygon-editor-0.2.1.zip&can=2&q=)

run it via

```
java -jar polygon-editor.jar
```

after adding an image, you can draw a polygon on the canvas and then save it as a .psh file, but it actually doesn't care about the file extension :)